# Rails 5 - Simple_form and has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, simple-form

*models/video*

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :category, through: :video_category
  has_one :video_category
end
```

*models/category*

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :video_categories
  has_many :videos, through: :video_categories
end
```

One video can have only one category, but one category have several videos.

I let the users post video links and let them choose the best category for each video. I created some categories in admin and they can use only the ones I created.

*views/videos/new*

```
<%= simple_form_for @new_video do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :title %>
   <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
   <%= f.input :category,
               as: :select,
               label: "Category" %>
   <%= f.button :submit, "Submit", class:"btn btn-danger post-button-form" %>
<% end %>
```

Instead of having the categories, I just have the choice between "Yes" or "No" 
I can't use f.associations instead of f.input because I have an error saying I can't use associations with a "has_one" relationship.

What can I do ? I'm really stuck :(

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `has_many_through` here for this simple association (as far as I see now), it is a bit over complicated. You could simply use normal 1 to many association without this third model (VideoCategory). But In your case:

1. VideoContrller:

`params.require(:video).permit(:name, :description, video_categories_attributes: [:id, :foo, :bar])`

2. video.rb:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :video_category`

3. Database tables must contain:

> ```
> videos:
>  video_category_id:integer
> categories:
>  video_category_id:integer
> video_categories:
>  video_id:integer
>  category_id:integer
> ```

4. Now you can set or create a VideoCategory record from the Video cotroller. Try in console:

`Video_category.create!`

`Video.last.video_category = 1`

But I think for your case it would be easier to simply use one to many assoc, without the JoinedModel.

Hope this will get you on tracks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You're right, a one to many association is much better for my case. I modified my model and now everything is working fine.

Comment: Nice, very glad it helped